# Run dialog within RDP for both 2003 & 2008

Tags: remote-desktop, autohotkey

Technically this isn't an Autohotkey question, but I figured this audience might know the answer... There are a lot of hotkeys within RDP an RDP session, but amazingly nothing for the RUN dialog.

I'm looking for *single* a way to present the RUN dialog from within an RDP session to either a 2003 or 2008 server. Within 2003 targets, ALT HOME R brings up the actual run dialog. Within 2008 ALT HOME opens the start menu dialog that defaults to a field similar to run, and this works for my needs. But on 2008 ALT HOME R finds the first item in the start menu that begins with. I've also explored using the arrow keys, but 2008 is 2 up arrows, and 2003 is 3 up arrows.

What I'm looking for is a *single* keystroke (which I can autohotkey) that opens the RUN dialog on both OS's?

Comment: Sorry, I've not used Windows Server before. Does Windows Key R not work?

Comment: I use the Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection Manger tool, and not in full screen mode. I've got a pair of large screens, don't need to. When not in full screen, WinR opens the local run dialog, not the Run dialog with the RDP session.

Comment: Would there be anything in the titlebar maybe that would let you know which kind of session you have open? If so you could send a different keyboard shortcut with AHK depending on the titlebar text? Or maybe it would be feasible to use AHK to make the window fullscreen, send WinR and then take DRP out of full screen with a single hotkey? Sorry, I don't have the same environment to actually test with.

Comment: The titlebar contains the name of the server for the active session, but that does not include the OS version. Hoping there is a normal screen equivalent of "Win R" just like ALT Pg Up/Down is the normal screen equivalent of ALT TAB.

Comment: Would it work to `Send {Alt Down}{Home Down}R{Alt Up}{Home Up}` -- simulating all three keys pressed at once?

Comment: That threw an error "this line does not contain a recognized action". Replaced with SEND !{Down}{Home}{Down}R!{Up}{Home}{Up} but that does not present the run dialog in either OS version.

Comment: win+r can be achieved by `PostMessage, 0x111, 401, , , ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd ;WM_COMMAND`, if that's useful (tested on Windows 7)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are in fullscreen, generally it will not capture most windows hotkey keystrokes, as the local end will "swallow" them before the RDP window sees them.
You can try using `ControlSend` to route the input to the RDP window, but I do not think you will have much luck.

If you have clipboard sharing working while not in fullscreen, then you could maybe have a script running on each remote server that monitors the clipboard, and if it finds some magic string, executes some command.

If all else fails, when they key is hit that you want to send to the remote session, you could always contextually block the key while RDP is the active window (So it does not execute on the local session) using `#IfWinActive`, then fullscreen the RDP window, then send the key sequence, then restore the RDP window to it's original size.

As a side note - why do you not use Fullscreen RDP windows?
If your reason is that it is a pain to switch between the various windows that you have open, then I have a solution:
[This Script](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=10025) will let you switch between fullscreen RDP windows by placing your mouse pointer against the edge of the RDP window, and rolling the mouse wheel. It only needs to be running on the local machine.